# Word-wrap radio button text in Java?

Tags: java, swing, radio-button

I have some radio buttons whose text may be very long.  Is there an easy way to word-wrap them?

Yes, wrapping them in `<html>` tags and inserting `<br>` tags would work, but is there a more automatic way to accomplish this?  I don't really want to roll my own typesetter.

Answer (score 8):

The quickest and dirtiest way is simply to prepend <html> at the start of the radio button's label text. This will make line wrapping start to occur but you'll now need to be careful about that text if it has < characters in it. This also maintains the functionality of click on the label text being a click on the radio button.

Here's a cheap and cheerful example:

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private Test() {
        Container  c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        c.add( new JRadioButton( "<html>I've got a very long text description that's going to wrap over very long lines because I stuck an &lt;html&gt; tag at the start of its label string.</html>") );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setSize( 200,200 );
        setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Works very well and is a short solution. It's dirty and would work if you put an </html> at the end. it would be nicer ;)

Comment: Since you asked so nicely! :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there are any perfect solutions for this. Other than using `<br>` tags, you could use a `JTextArea` and make it look like a label. Then set `lineWrap` and `wrapStyleWord` to `true`.

Then, you lose the functionality of clicking on the labels to select/deselect your radio button, so you will have to add a mouse listener.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping them in `<html>` tags and making sure they get enough vertical space should work. No need to break the lines yourself.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?  I tried this with practically every Layout and this didn't work with any of them.